# remove last character from pyspark df columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

i'm reading csv file with pyspark like this : `df = spark.read.format('csv').options(header=True, encoding='windows-1251',delimiter=';').load('csv_file.csv')`

in the result in columns i got string with " ' " single quote character, like this `12435'`

there is not a single line in the file with a quote at the end, idk where spark finds it

i need to remove this quote

btw pandas read csv withot quote at the end of every row, but i cant translate pd.DF to spark.DF, i got error `cannot merge type DoubleType and StringType`

DF has some empty cols

i tried:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
for i in df.columns:
    df.withColumn(i, expr("substring({name}, 1, length({name}) -1)".format(name=i)))
 
 
for i in df.columns:
    df.withColumn(i, col(i).substr(lit(0), length(col(i)) - 1))
```

none of this helped me

ty

read df

```
col1 | col2
12345' abcde'
```

expected output

```
col1 | col2
12345  abcde
```

Comment: Can you share a sample from your input and expected output?

Comment: @DKNY added, ty for ur time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension

```
df.select(*[regexp_replace(F.col(c),"'",'').alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()

+-----+-----+
| col1| col2|
+-----+-----+
|12345|abcde|
+-----+-----+
```